# Unable to add nuget package for CsvHelper in Azure function from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, function, nuget, csvhelper

I want to use CsvHelper in azure function V2. I added following code in function.proj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
    <PropertyGroup>  
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>  
    </PropertyGroup>  
    <ItemGroup>  
        <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="15.0.5" />
    </ItemGroup>  
</Project>
```

Also, imported this using following
#r "CsvHelper"

But it gives error as
[Error] run.csx(3,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'CsvHelper' could not be found.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Open VS  IDE, enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`NuGet Package Manager`-->`Package Sources` and check if you have checked `nuget.org` as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources). If not, you can add it manually.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and then build it again. Make sure you don't have any other errors in project.